# fancybox url rewrite & back button

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox, back-button

I use fancybox to do a small project to clone pinterest.
When user click photo, the browser will popup the image box and the url will be changed.
If user close the popup, the popup will be closed and the url will be back(not change page).

I use these function(below) to achieve and it works fine.  However, i face one problem now which is 
when I click the photo, browser give me popup,  then i refresh the page, the page will go that url, but now i click back button, the page doesn't go back(url is back, view doesn't back). Can anyone solve this problem?

function:

```
window.history.replaceState(); window.history.pushState(); $(window).bind('popstate');
```

Thank you, all.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is the hash url. Fancybox has hash settings on by default meaning when you click on a url the url gets appended with a hash(#) + phrase if you are using gallery option. To remove simply initiate the default settings for hash to false like so:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
   $.fancybox.defaults.hash = false;
}
```

now you can go back and forward without Fancybox interfering with your browser's history

Answer (score 0):

have you try :

```
window.history.back()
```